# Random number function returns same number every time i run the code in kotlin with jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

This is my code;

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            StackOverFlowQuestionExampleTheme {
                val randomNumber =(0..10).random()
                println(randomNumber)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result (every time);

```
I/System.out: 9
```

Why is that and how to get random number every time i call?

edit; I see that when we reproduce the same code, you do not get the same result, so I am editting the question. I get this result when I use jetpack compose, maybe that's the problem.

edit2; I edited the question title, because I realized that the problem was caused by jetpack compose.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://pl.kotl.in/29t8foL7D)

Comment: As @Sweeper said, the code as shared works fine. Please share more code. Your problem is likely due to fact that `random()` is not called as many times as you think, and we need the actual structure of the code to explain why.

Comment: (@Sweeper funny enough, I got 9 from your snippet on first try and I was like "damn, is that true?" - then running again gave different results and I trusted my sanity again)

Comment: Put `println((0..10).random())` in a loop… It won't print the same number every time!

Comment: As already commented, this is not reproducible. However, if you _want_ it to be reproducible (e.g. to have consistent test data), create a `Random` generator with a constant seed: `val r = Random(0)` and then use `(0..10).random(r)`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer gonna be useful, try this code, it works fine to me:

```kotlin
            val generatByRandom = Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
            val randomNumber= randomGenerator.nextInt(0, 10)
            println(randomNumber)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use something like that more accurate

```
  val myRandomValues = List(1) { Random.nextInt(0, 10) }
  val myRandomValues = List(5) { Random.nextInt(0, 30) }
```

output here ex  : [8, 21, 16, 29, 16]

or

```
 val random1 = (0..100).shuffled().last()
```

Answer (score -1):

From `geeksforgeeks` i found the same code as you used but there is some changes As below. May be helpful to you

For Kotlin>=1.3

```
 val randomNumber = (0..10).random()
 println(randomNumber)
```

For Kotlin<1.3

```
val randomNumber = Random().nextInt(10+1 - 0) + 0
println(randomNumber)
```

Source Link : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-a-range-in-android/